# Fermat's Last Theorem (FLT) in standard model space corresponding to an infinite Blaschke product

Tags: functional-equations, blaschke-products

Let $u$ be an inner function and denote by $H^2$ the Hardy space on the open unit disc D. A model space $K_u$ associated to $u$ is a Hilbert space of the form $K_u=(uH^2)^⊥$ where ⊥ denotes the orthogonal complement in $H^2$.  Does FLT still true in $K_u$ when u is an infinite Blaschke product ?

NB: It was shown that FLT is true for $K_u$ when u is a finite Blaschke product (cf. *Stephan Ramon Garcia, Javad Mashreghi, William T. Ross - Introduction to Model Spaces and their Operators-Cambridge University Press (2016),* **p. 125**).

What about the general case when $u$ is an arbitrary inner function ?

Comment: Could you explain what does FLT mean in the context of holomorphic functions?

Comment: Prove or disprove that there is no f,g,h in $K_u$ such that $$f^n+g^n=h^n$$ when $dim(span(f,g,h))>1$ and $n>2$ (cf.  *Stephan Ramon Garcia, Javad Mashreghi, William T. Ross - Introduction to Model Spaces and their Operators-Cambridge University Press (2016)*, **p. 125**. Here is a link : https://libgen.is/search.php?req=Introduction+to+Model+Spaces+and+their+Operators&open=0&res=25&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def)